# ArcGIS Pro failed to connect to PostgreSQL 11 database

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-pro

I'd like to connect from ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2 to a PostGIS database in PostgreSQL 11.2.
I am able to access via pgAdmin 4 to the respective databse. The link and access with my credentials is working for other systems e.g. QGIS etc. The steps were "insert" "connections" "new database connections" filling in my credentials then I get following error message:

> failed to connect to specified DBMS instance, a database connection
>   exception has occurred. underlying DBMS error(FATAL:no pg_hba_conf
>   entry fsqlstate=)

As I am able to connect from other systems I don't know what is missing in the pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: That's a PostgreSQL error message. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact release of PostgreSQL 11 deployed, and whether you can connect from psql or pgAdmin from that same Pro client host.

Comment: it is PostgreSQL 11.2 and I am able to connect via pgAdmin4 without problems

Comment: I found a way to connect via the postgres (superuser) password, this seems to work. With the user admin password it is still not possible

Comment: It's not best practice to use the `postgres` login for normal connection purposes (in fact, it's a *huge* security risk). If the admin login can connect, then you have to wonder if your non-priviliged login is correctly configured. Esri Tech Support may be able to help.

Comment: yes, I agree I don't like to use the postgres login, interestingly it works while the the others not...Thank you for your suggestion, I will try.

Comment: Sounds like the *pg-hba-conf* file is not set to allow the IP address of the Client PC (ArcGIS pro) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Comment: yes, but what is different with ArcGis Pro? The access from the same IP adress of the client PC is possible with other programms e.g. QGis, Pg Admin..